# How to compile FontForge?

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit, compiling

Who knows right way to compile FontForge on the Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit system?

Any experience and suggests will be greatly useful.

Full guide for build and install from source here:
[***FontForge :*** Building and installing from source](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/source-build.html#src-source)

... but my probe was failed. Help please.

Comment: Can you provide the failure you saw? It probably has useful information.

Comment: Sorry I do not answered you when I create my question because I was need to find just simple right way to compile FF. And btw my failure was approximately equal to @BD-TH answer (look below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
bzr branch lp:fontforge
cd fontforge
./configure
make 
sudo make install
```

I started it, by typing in the terminal `fontforge`.

[image: fontforge]

Comment: first at `./configure` I get "No GUI version" message.
I install dependence packages by guide and was configured with no this message but get this at `make`:
`pythonui.c:34:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: found answer here: [link](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.fonts.fontforge.devel/7341)
missing `python-dev` package

Comment: I get working copy of **FontForge** on my system, but just with installing additional dependence packages on my system **and** reinstall **FontForge** through **Software Center** ... will try to compile also. Thank you!

Comment: If you have the "pythonui.c:34:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory" error, try to install python-dev package.